# Is there a way to set SSMS only allows to run when code is selected

Tags: ssms

I am pretty new to SSMS and I am starting to make scripts. Sometimes I click on Run without selecting my code and you can imagine that it has consequences on the database.

I wanted to ask you if there is a possible configuration on SSMS so that the run button is not accessible when we have code selected?

Kind Regards

Comment: This feels like you should just be being vigilant to ensure you do (or don't) have the SQL you want to run selected, if I am honest. The feature is very common between SQL IDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting SET NOEXEC ON before the query guaranties that the SQL Server engine will check the syntax and object reference errors (during compilation), but it will not execute the actual query.

If you want prevent distract F5 or EXEC without have checked if you're executing something dangerous, put it before each script that you are making.

Comment: But if I do that i have to SET NOEXEC OFF before each querry too?

Actually i'm asking if there is something wich disable the run button before we have selected some code

Comment: No, or you need to disable the F5 function too. 
The only safe exec is the one that you mastery.

Comment: thanks a lot for your asnwer ! But i'm sad to hear there is nothing to prevent that with a disable of F5 button

Comment: If your problem is only the F5 and not the excute button, you can change the F function on your preferences I think.